# Trying to make an each method, like in jQuery, with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

```
Element.prototype.each = function(fn) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    fn(i);
  } 
};

var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

li.each(function(i) {
  this.style.borderBottom = '1px solid red';
});
```

I'm trying to make an each method like in jQuery. I tried many things in the for loop and in the callback but I got errors. I'm sure this is something to do with the 'this' context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use call to set context

**EDIT** : `Element` was not the right class, it should be `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection`

```
NodeList.prototype.each = HTMLCollection.prototype.each = function(fn) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    fn.call(this, i);
  } 
};
```

When you use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it allows you to bind a context AKA `this` to a function

There are 3 ways AFAIK to do this:

- [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (as said above)
- [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (which works like call except it takes only two arguments, the second being an array)
- [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (which is used for [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying))

---

Also note that as of [DOM level 4 (ES6 harmony)](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#collections:-elements) there is a new class called `Elements` which extends `Array` and is meant to replace `NodeList`/`HTMLCollection`, so you wouldn't need to actually extend it in ES6 to add an `each` method and use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead (though you won't be able to use `this` in your callback.

Comment: Voting up, but I would like to see a bit of explanation.

Comment: There is only one problem with this answer - it doesn't work. ;) `Element` instances does not have `.length` property nor numerical indexes.

Comment: it would be better to build a single .toArray() or ._() method, which would then let you use all the pre-existing array methods, not just forEach...

Comment: Woahh that was fast! It works!

Thank you very much. I'm gonna take a look at NodeList and HTMLCollection at MDN for more information. Again many thanks for your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByTagName('li')` returns `HTML Collection` object, not `Element`.

It's quite easy to duplicate jQuery `each` (the only difference between native `forEach` and `$.each` is order of parameters - `$.each` uses `(i,el)` tuple, `[].forEach` uses `(el,i)` tuple). In modern browsers (all except IE8) you can just use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li').constructor.prototype.each = function(fn,thisArg) {
    [].forEach.call(this, function(el,i,array) {
        fn.call(thisArg, i,el,array);
    });
};
```

I don't recommend to extend native prototypes, you should use  `[].forEach.call(yourNodeList, func)` instead. It's possible to do `yourNodeList = [].slice.call(yourNodeList);` to convert your DOM collection to plain array.

Comment: No, jQuery does not extend any native prototype. Extending native prototypes can introduce subtle bugs in behavior of most of existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had cause to solve a particular problem in a similar manner and was interested to see how others had approached it.  Bearing in mind the caveats posted about extending native prototypes, I'm just logging my solution, implemented in a browser environment only, for posterity.

```
/* For Arrays, enumerable Objects,
   DOMTokenLists and HTMLCollections etc */
Object.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    (Array.isArray(this) ? this : (this.constructor.name === 'Object' ? Object.keys(this) : [].slice.call(this))).forEach(fn);
};
```

:)